# How to check all machines have same datetime?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, networking, ntp

I have more that one machine and all machines have same datetime(including miliseconds).

Now I want to check all machines have same time or not !

we can do it by calling single thread for every machine to collect its datetime through wmi or any another option but it will never gives you expected result.

So what is best way to check all machines have same datetime?

Is there any command to check all machines times are equal?

Note: All machines are communicate with each other but there is **no** server.

Comment: I don't know how I would ensure that in code, but if you use the same [NTP servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) on all machines then you could be reasonably sure that the time difference is within an acceptable limit.

Comment: as @Dirk already tried to tell you: the best way to do this is by using tools that are already there - ask your IT guys they will surely already have something setup to ensure this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_server)